# Deploying websites with git (or generally: deployment workflow)

Tags: wordpress, git, deployment, workflow

So I do create websites since some years already but I never cared about a good workflow. So I did bad things like working on the production server etc.

I want to improve all that and so I came across git and tools like wordmove (for wordpress).

I tried to visualize what I want or what I think could work:
[workflow visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7ApA.png)

Now I think something there is "wrong" or "not so good" and can be done better but I dont really know what or how to do it.

So I have my local machine where I develop, then I have a bitbucket repository, a staging server to show the customer the current status and a production server which is the live server of the customer.

I'd appreciate some help :P How it can be understood.

Answer (score 0):

From git 2.3, a feature named "Push to deploy" was added, you can search document for it or read [here](https://www.cedric-meury.ch/2015/02/trying-out-the-push-to-deploy-feature-of-git-2-3/)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. Since now I only heard of the post-receive-file method.

Answer (score 0):

What type of websites are you making? WordPress, Drupal, ect? It looks like you're on the right track.

As that diagram shows, I'd recommend creating a `development`, `staging`, and `production` branch for each project and setting up a webhook for the repo that listens for pushes and deploys (and builds) accordingly. This way you can deploy to private servers to "stage" your project/features for the client first before merging in to `production`.

[stackahoy.io](https://stackahoy.io/) is built to do exactly this. It's free for 1 repo and unlimited branches. Some benefits to using Stackahoy are:

- Maintain deployments for your git repositories in one place
- Maintain static configuration files (stuff you keep in the .gitignore file)
- Preform post-deployment scripts
- Securely and instantly deploy your code based on the branch that was pushed and see real-time logs as it deploys.
- Deploy to multiple servers at once (good for load-balanced applications)

*Disclaimer: I work for Stackahoy and would be happy to answer any Q's.*